# Splitting actions file into multiple files

Tags: reactjs, redux

The actions files in my React app are getting really large and difficult to manage. This is happening despite the fact that I already have multiple actions file i.e. userActions.js, accountActions.js, etc. These files are so verbose that I need to keep scrolling up and down to find a particular action that I need.

I had the idea of splitting an actions file for a module into multiple files and then import them into a parent level file so that in my React components I still import a single actions file.

It's important to keep in mind that I'm splitting actions file for a single module. I already have multiple actions files for different domains of the app. What I'm saying is that the actions file for even a single module is getting large.

I'm a bit confused about how this would work though.

Say, I have a bunch of files like these. I'd save the following as module1UserActions.js

```
export const userAction1 = (value) => {
    return {
        type: types.ACTION1,
        value
    };
}

export const userAction2 = (value) => {
    return {
        type: types.ACTION2,
        value
    };
}
```

Then, let's say I have the module1AccountActions.js file that looks like this:

```
export const accountAction1 = (value) => {
    return {
        type: types.ACTION3,
        value
    };
}

export const accountAction2 = (value) => {
    return {
        type: types.ACTION4,
        value
    };
}
```

If I wanted to bring all of them together in a single file that I can import in my components, how would I bring them together? Say, the following is module1Actions.js that brings the individual files together. I guess that file would only contains a bunch of imports.

```
import * as userActions from 'module1UserActions';
import * as accountActions from 'module1AccountActions';
```

And then import that single file in my component but I think I'd run into issues with action names, right?

```
import * as actions from 'module1Actions';
```

But I think when I need to use the userAction1, I'd have to call it as `actions.userActions.userAction1`

Would this approach work?

Comment: Confusing to me what your actual question is and what this has to do with react but I think what you are talking about is as simple as `function aliased() {
    return importedService.funcName();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your actions explicitly in your actions file.

```
import * as userActions from 'userActions';
import * as accountsActions from 'accountActions';

export {
  ...userActions,
  ...accountActions,
};
```

I'm using the spread operator (`...`) to flatten the resulting object. You can import and call your actions now like this:

```
import * as actions from 'actions';

actions.userAction1();
```

Comment: The export part with the spread was the missing piece! Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting an error where the spread operator is. I suspect this is due to spread still being in proposal stage. I then tried using Object.assign i.e. const myActions = Object.assign({}, actions1, actions2). This works but couldn't figure out how to export it. If I do export default myActions, it works but then I need to add "default" before I can call the action i.e. actions.default.someAction(); How do I export it without default?

Comment: You can export it as the default value and import it without an alias with `import actions from 'actions';`

Comment: I'm trying the exact same code, but it can't compile using `...userActions`. The `...` are throwing a `Syntax error: Unexpected token` error. Not sure why.

Comment: The spread operator is a feature of ES2017 (I think so). So you have to transpile it with a transpiler like Babel. You could either use the babel-preset-es2017 or you could stick with es2016 and import the spread operator only with the plugin. Just take a look at the Babel website to configure your transpiler.

Comment: using `export default { ...userActions, ...accountActions  }` avoids that syntax error warning (note the `default` keyword).